# How to handle Crash with setHasTransientState() on android 4.0.3?

Tags: android, animation

I am seeing this crash on android 4.0.3 version. All above versions are working fine. How to solve this crash ?

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setHasTransientState
        at com.techmash.playo.fragments.AddFavAreaFragment$AreaAdapter$ViewHolder.onClick(AddFavAreaFragment.java:338)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3524)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14194)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4476)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:816)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:583)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

This method available in SDK starting API level 16. You can use **ViewCompat** from support library for previous versions.

```
ViewCompat.setHasTransientState(view, true);
```